# How can I add upload field in user post in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to add upload field in user post, my idea is to give PDF uploading functionality with every user post. So the user can post PDF with some description.

Comment: Can you give a bit more information. Is this self-hosted Wordpress or wordpress.com for example, and do you plan to add the upload field in the html of the editor in wp-admin or through code in the template files? -- Speaks to whether you have ftp/server access or not

Comment: What's wrong with using the "Add Media" option already provided in WordPress?

Comment: Liam Beiley: It is self hosted wordpress,

Comment: BenM: I can add a static custom field, but the issue is, i want to give functionality to the user to upload or attach PDF, if I use this statically how would i manage  PDF files to fetch by categories etc

Comment: Can anyone help me for this ?

Comment: Liam Bailey: Presently I am working this project on localhost. My idea is to customize through code in template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this link for image uploading from client side, if you want to upload pdf files from client side you have to do some changes for this plugin.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-public-uploader