# How to add pdf upload functionality in wordpress user post

Tags: php, wordpress, pdf

I want to add pdf upload functionality in user post, I was trying this with Quick Post Widget, but unable to upload PDF with that.

Comment: can you provide some code reference ?

Comment: I didn't customize that yet, just used "quick post widget", and "user submitted post", actually i want to give pdf uploading functionality to the user.

Comment: the user has to post with the quick post widget? or can you use regular form from the back-end? if you can use the back-end then you don't have to add anything it's built in with the "Add Media" button.

Comment: possible problem with the script which is checking file extension, 

you must be familiar with `$_FILES(name)(type) = 'applocation/pdf'` there must be a condition in your script which is checking file extension,so you need to check that condition and see if above mentioned condition is there or not..

Comment: Please do not post duplicate questions only because you did not get an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10700350/how-can-i-add-upload-field-in-user-post-in-wordpress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step would be to give the user a form element to interact with using the enctype on your form.

```
<form action="yourpage.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    <input type="file" name="upfile">
</form>
```

The important part is the enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute.

This will upload the file to a temporary location. You will then want to use PHP to move the file into a location that makes sense. Right away in PHP you will have access to the $_FILES global variable.

The following tutorial should help explain it better then I can -> http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php

Comment: Thanks folks for helping me, I have got a plugin for this, "WordPress User Frontend" which gives user pdf uploading functionality on button click. . Thanks anyway.